# How to Show QR Code in RDLC report

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rdlc, qr-code

I used QrEncoder (NuGet Package QrCode.Net) for generating QR Code in MVC 4. Now my question is how can I show this QR code in my RDLC Report dynamically. I searched through many websites but didn't got any feasible Solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to:

- Create a handler in .net to dynamically generate the QR code based on querystring parameters and return it as a png.
- setup the rdlc to have an image that is externally referenced.
- when generating the report you will need to set it to allow external references
- pass the url to the handler/image in the dataset being sent to the report and have that be the path for the image in the report.

When the report is generated it will then generate and show the QR code.

Answer (score 0):

```
     var data = db.spMemberDetailByMembership(CompanyId, BranchId, Convert.ToInt32(MemRegId)).Select(x => new SPMemberRegisterModel
            {

                ID = x.ID,             
                BookingPrice = x.BookingPrice,
                MailingAddress = MailingAddress(x.ID),
                BarCode = GenerateQrCode(x.UUID),

            }).ToList();

  reportdatasource.Value = data;
   localReport.DataSources.Add(reportdatasource);

    private byte[] GenerateQrCode(string qrmsg)
                {
                    QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator qRCodeGenerator = new QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator();
                    QRCoder.QRCodeData qRCodeData = qRCodeGenerator.CreateQrCode(qrmsg, QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
                    QRCoder.QRCode qRCode = new QRCoder.QRCode(qRCodeData);
                    Bitmap bmp = qRCode.GetGraphic(5);

                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                    imgBarCode.Height = 150;
                    imgBarCode.Width = 150;
                    using (Bitmap bitMap = qRCode.GetGraphic(5))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                            byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
                            return byteImage;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please consider explaining how this works.

Comment: - First Install QrCoder Nugut Package then pass value of QR code in
       this Function after that select add image in rdlc and then select
       value from dataset